# How to count probability for the composite string column using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here is my table em

```
pair count prob
a|||a 2
a|||book 1
a|||is 2
book|||a 1
book|||book 1
book|||is 1
```

For example : `if I want to calculate a|||a prob = (a|||a count)/(when left string 'a' appearance)=2/(2+1+2)=0.4` 
and update this prob to third column `prob`
, so `a|||book =1/(2+1+2) ....book|||is =(book|||is count)/when left sting 'book' appearance) =1/(1+1+1)`

Is there any proper way implement in MySQL code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps:
1. create a table **sum_of_counts**

```
create table 
sum_of_counts(wild_pair varchar(10),sum int);
```

2.run this query to calculate sum of the counts and to insert them into table **sum_of_counts**

```
insert into sum_of_counts 
  select substring(pair,1,locate('|',pair)),sum(count) 
   from em group by substring(pair,1,locate('|',pair))
```

3. update your table **em** with the probablity

   update em set prob=count/select sum from sum_of_count where wild_pair=substring(pair,1,locate('|',pair))